# AWS Lambda Serverless deploy asking for AWS provider credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have configured serverless with key and secret.

When i try to run serverless deploy it says:

```
ServerlessError: AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here:.
```

Please help me what to do

Comment: Maybe https://serverfault.com/ is a better place to ask these types of questions.

Comment: How did you configure serverless with key and secret?

Comment: Follow the official documentation is good enough:
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/credentials/#creating-aws-access-keys

Answer (score 24):

This is how to setup AWS credentials on the local:

1. Sign in to AWS console
2. Go to your AWS account overview
3. Account menu in the upper-right (has your name on it)
4. sub-menu: Security Credentials
5. Copy `<Access Key ID>`
6. Copy `<Secret Access Key>`
7. Run on local `serverless config credentials --provider aws --key <Access Key ID> --secret <Secret Access Key>`

Answer (score 11):

You can set up your serverless credentials by using the `serverless config credentials` command, with `--provider aws` and using `--key` and `--secret` to set your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key, respectively.

See [the Serverless AWS - Config Credentials documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/cli-reference/config-credentials/) for Serverless specifics, and [this AWS document on security credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys) in case you need to figure out what your credentials are.

Answer (score 3):

Also give your profile and region configuration in your yml file

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python2.7
  lambdaHashingVersion: 20201221
  profile: 'serverless-admin'
  region: 'us-east-1'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I try everything. I configure my credentials (AWS key and secret) with both aws cli and serverless cli but still got that same error when I run:

```
sls deploy -v
```

I was using CMD before then I realize something when I run the command

```
aws configure list
```

the output is

```
 Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key     ****************SOU5 shared-credentials-file
secret_key     ****************Cki5 shared-credentials-file
    region                eu-west-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

the path of the config file is

> ~/.aws/config

and CMD don't know what ~/ PATH IS but Bash does know

then I run the

```
 sls deploy -v
```

on bash terminal and it worked ‍

Answer (score 0):

For those who has the same problem, even when already configured the AWS credentials for serverless, by running the command serverless config credentials:

I had the same problem; even when I had set up properly my AWS credentials on serverless, when I run the serverless deploy command, I got this: ServerlessError: AWS provider credentials not found.

How did I solved it? By installing and configuring the AWS [CLI Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/es/cli/). Once I installed it and configured it with my AWS credentials, and then run again the serverless deploy command, it just works fine.

I guess the serverless command, behind the scenes, uses the AWS CLI to access AWS and provision the AWS resources.

I hope this could be helpful for someone.